# What is full scale?

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-detection, signal-power

I read the Wikipedia documentation and it's not clear to me what is the full scale concept. What is the meaning of changing the full scale? How I can preserve data in that scale?

Comment: Yes, i read this onehttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_scale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the amplitude of signal that corresponds to the maximum that a system can represent. For example, if you have a 8-bit analog-to-digital converter (ADC), this system can represent $2^8=256$ possible values, where $0$ counts corresponds to the minimum voltage, and $255$ counts corresponds to the maximum voltage.

Now, what voltage this $255$ counts physically maps to can be chosen (usually with an external reference that you provide the converter). For example, if you tell the device that $255$ counts corresponds to $5\textrm{V}$, then the full scale is $5\textrm{V}$, and you can measure signals that reach all the way up to this range.

However, you could as well set $255$ counts to correspond to $5\textrm{mV}$, and in that case the full scale is $5\textrm{mV}$. If you were to send in the same $5\textrm{V}$ as in the previous case then you would saturate the device.

The reason for changing the full scale is to maximise the [dynamic range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range#Electronics), so you can match your detection system nicely to the signal you are trying to measure.